# Gradle File Change After Update Android studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, gradle

i need to update my gradle (project) and add

ext {
.... }
and dependency to it

but   After Update Android studio Chipmunk the gradle (project) change and dependency,ext area are hidden

so how to add it to the the right place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually add `buildscript` and `dependencies` tag so your whole `build.gradle` (project level) will look like this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // other dependencies you wanna add
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```